# Basic knowledge about server cluster

Tags: linux, cluster

I work in a small office with, maybe, 15 workstations and a server that I've recently deployed running Ubuntu Server 20.04. I discovered some redundunt servers that makes me think about creating a cluster for performance and safety. I'm thinking of creating a cluster of 3 servers, 1 master and 2 nodes. And the questions are:

1. Do all three of them have to have the same OS (Ubuntu Server 20.04 in my case) and the same configuration of software (Apache, PHP, MySql) or maybe the 2 nodes have to be exactly the same and the master can have only the software for managing the nodes?
2. The IP that router poins to the server in port 80 is the IP of the master or the 1st node?

Thanks in advance and excuse my english

Comment: You haven't said what you're trying to cluster. Saying that you want to cluster the servers doesn't tell us anything. What are you trying to cluster? Email, file, print, web, etc.?

Comment: You are right joeqwerty. The server I want to cluster is a web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try building a small load balancer as your stategy. That would help simplify the process theoretically anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below link it will helps you to create a Web server cluster.

[Create a Web server cluster](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-high-availability-clustering-in-centos-ubuntu/)